# Python shebang line not working - how to cleanup python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I'm trying to learn some Python to make my life easier with some scripts.

I've created a script, which uses tKinter. Unfortunately, there is a bug in the Python 3.9 and the installed version via Brew (on MacOS 12). I've looked up and seems the only way to fix this, is to install the Python directly from Python.org

I've done this and it fixed my issue. As mentioned in the title, the script is only running, when I "hard" link the interpreter in the shebang line
`#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3`

I've I use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` the bug occurs again (black tk window).

So, from a beginner's perspective, I can't figure out what is missing.
The only thing I would assume is that my old Brew install (which I uninstalled)

I also cleaned the hash

```
% env python -V      
Python 3.10.4
% python -V
Python 3.10.4
% /usr/bin/env python -V                      
Python 3.10.4
% cat .bash_profile 
alias python='python3'
PYTHONPATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"
export PYTHONPATH
% echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g' | sort | uniq -c
   1 /Library/Apple/usr/bin
   1 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin
   1 /bin
   1 /opt/X11/bin
   1 /opt/homebrew/bin
   3 /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin
   1 /opt/homebrew/sbin
   1 /sbin
   1 /usr/bin
   1 /usr/local/bin
   1 /usr/sbin
% declare -p PATH                             
export -T PATH path=( /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin /opt/homebrew/bin /opt/homebrew/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/X11/bin /Library/Apple/usr/bin )
%
```

Is my Path variable the problem of it? How would I clean it?

Comment: `$PATH` is searched in order, so if you want your python.org version of `python3` to be run first, put its directory at the beginning of your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Ok, I've cleaned the `PATH`up ```/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin```
 But the error still exists.

Comment: Uh, what does `which python3` say?  The shebang, at least in the format you are using (which should be at the top of the question, not buried in the middle) relies on that.  Also, is there a virtualenv involved in this or not?  That again modifies what `which python3` will return.

Comment: `which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
`

Comment: I've checked with platform.python_version() and somehow with the mentioned shebang is running with 3.8.9

Comment: the `echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g'` is a neat trick, but `sort` after kinda defeats the purpose, does it not?  I don't know, I remain confused.  You say the shebang only works with the full path to "...Versions/3.10/bin/python3".  but that's also what you say the `which python3` returns.  It's odd that one would work but not the other.  Also, is there an actual error message, not "doesn't work".

Comment: Ok, I found the reason. xcode installed a python 3.8.9 in the folder `library/developer/commandlinetools/usr/bin/python3`But I have no idea "how to ignore" it. I could remove xcode, but this would be only plan b

Comment: In absolute terms you need to put a discoverable python3 earlier in the $PATH than the one xcode drops in.  Again, please don't **sort** your PATH because that is completely messing up your troubleshooting here.

Comment: Ok. So Now I'm completly lost. From my knowledge and understanding this would be done by adding the Path via `export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin` right? 

So this would be mean, if I add this line into the .bash-profile it should be fixed, or?

Comment: No, in your proposal you are putting `...3.10/bin` at the tail end of things, where every other python will be found **before** your desired one.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you wrote it with a space above. It should be `#!usr/bin/env/python3`.

Comment: try `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:$PATH`  but you can do this in a terminal window in bash and check how things go. I'd write BUPPATH=$PATH first and then you can just export PATH=$BUPPATH to restore things.